# login with facebook without any plugin for phonegap

Tags: javascript, facebook, cordova

I want to make a facebook login button in my application using javascript SDK of facebook, the problem is when I tryed to login with facebook it opens the default browser showing an error telling url problem having issues with cross domain.

I would like to know if I can make the button without any plugin because when I search on google I always find plugins to make the facebook dialog be into the app and how to fix that problem to be able to load that dialog without having ajax communication problems.

I know to do this we need to have a facebook application to get the app ID and use the API with it but I'm using heruko hosting
I' need to know about the channel.html file how to use it to make cross ajax requests with the app.
thats all thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16576977/is-there-any-facebook-plugin-for-phonegap-2-7-0/16579592#16579592

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote a basic workflow for making a facebook login app using the childbrowser - 
https://github.com/DrewDahlman/phonegapFacebookApp

That should point you in the right direction.

Comment: thank you for your super fast response but I'm still wondering when Ill finish this how to use the plugins with the phonegap build because I dont have a mac to build the app for iphone.

Comment: the child browser is part of the phonegap build i believe... basically you're going to be interested in the portions where you hook up to Facebook. This workflow allows a user to login and give permissions and then you can take actions based on those permissions.

Comment: It's true we cannot do it without the childbrowser plugin hopefully we can add it to the project to the phonegap build.
Thank you so much for helping me.

Comment: childbrowser has now been replaced with the inappbrowser

Comment: @ClintonWard it has indeed. but the concept stays the same. Just don't use the calls for the childBrowser. I just did this in a new app and it still works just fine.

Comment: Any solution like this for Android?

Comment: really? oh! I will thest then and let you know!

Comment: I have the same requirement,My phonegap app wants to post some data on to facebook.I am not clear on what to use, either phonegap facebook plugin or jquery plugin or using childbrowser.I dont want to go out off my app scope.So thought of using Childbrowser.As I am using Cordova 2.7.0, childbrowser is been depricated.Please anyone give me the solution for this ..I am stuck :(